# Merge two tensorflow datasets into one dataset with inputs and labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have two tensorflow datasets that are generated using `timeseries_dataset_from_array` ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/timeseries_dataset_from_array)). One corresponds to the input of my network and the other one to the output. I guess we can call them the *inputs* dataset and the *targets* dataset, which are both the same shape (a timeseries window of a fixed size).

The code I'm using to generate these datasets goes like this:

```
train_x = timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    df_train['x'],
    None,
    sequence_length,
    sequence_stride=sequence_stride,
    batch_size=batch_size
)
train_y = timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    df_train['y'],
    None,
    sequence_length,
    sequence_stride=sequence_stride,
    batch_size=batch_size
)
```

The problem is that when calling `model.fit`, tf.keras expects that if a `tf.data.Dataset` is given in the `x` argument, it has to provide both the *inputs* and *targets*. That is why I need to combine these two datasets into one, setting one as *inputs* and the other one as *targets*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use `tf.data.Dataset.zip`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(100)
Y = X*2

sample_length = 20
input_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
  X, None, sequence_length=sample_length, sequence_stride=sample_length)
target_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
  Y, None, sequence_length=sample_length, sequence_stride=sample_length)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((input_dataset, target_dataset))

for x, y in dataset:
  print(x.shape, y.shape)
```

```
(5, 20) (5, 20)
```

You can then feed `dataset` directly to your model.

Comment: Sounds good. When I am able to test it I'll report back, thanks a lot